# Trying to calculate fog_index

Tags: python

im trying to calculate the fog index for same data on reviews, how ever, every time i run my code, i the the error: "AttributeError: 'TextStats' object has no attribute 'n_sent' and i dont know how to solve it, hope you guys can help.

```
   nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

fog_index = []
for i in range(len(reviews)):
    Tester = reviews[i]
    Tester = textacy.make_spacy_doc(Tester, lang = nlp)

    ts = textacy.text_stats.TextStats(Tester)

    sum_words = ts.n_words

    fog_index.append(0.4 * (sum_words / ts.n_sent + 100 * ts.n_polysyllable_words / sum_words))

fog_index = pd.DataFrame(fog_index)
fog_index.describe()
```

Comment: when i round the code i get the following error: AttributeError: 'TextStats' object has no attribute 'n_sent'

Comment: When you say `sum_words = ts.n_words`, you have a function called `n_words`. You need to write a function in the class `TextStats` that has `n_sent`.

Comment: `sum_words = ts.n_words()` perhaps?